# Shared variables in ASP.NET I'm Confused?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm a little confused... Im having trouble with my web application. Im building a system that generates quotes for customers. The customer requests a quote then multiple generated quotes can be sent out to them based on the original request.

In my .vb file I have:

```
Partial Class NewQuote
Private Shared GeneratedQuoteIDArray As New ArrayList
```

this GeneratedQuoteIDArray is then accessed and built up from several Protected Sub's.

I'm having difficulty in multi user environment. If someone is working on the same page the GeneratedQuoteIDArray is holding both users values :S.

Please help... I'm sure im just doing something stupid!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Shared` means that it's a static value which is attached to the definition of the class itself, not to any particular instance of it.  So there's only one within the context of the application.  That's why other code paths would change the same value and over-write each other's values.

It sounds like you're looking for an instance value, not a static value.  Like this:

```
Private GeneratedQuoteIDArray As New ArrayList
```

That way it'll be attached to any new instance of the class and private only to that instance.  So separate requests with separate instances will have separate values.

You can read more about `Shared` members [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hbsxy95%28v=VS.90%29.aspx), as well as many other places.  When researching this topic, the keywords you're looking for are "static vs. instance" in terms of variables, functions, etc.  You'll likely find a lot of C-style code explaining it, but you can think of it the same way in VB.  VB just calls it `Shared` instead of `static`.

Comment: Hi David, Thank you for your very full answer. I understand now! I'm having a strange problem though :( I use:
    GeneratedQuoteIDArray.Add(GeneratedQuoteID)
    Session("GeneratedQuoteIDs") = GeneratedQuoteIDArray

In each of my subs to build up the array. Now when I try to read this array from my session I only get the last item I added to the array. Any ideas?
    ar = Session("GeneratedQuoteIDs")

Comment: @Mr-Easily-Confused: Not sure.  I don't see any errors in those couple of lines of code (unless there's some quirk about types stored in `Session` that I don't know about).  It's possible code somewhere else is overwriting it.  I'd want to debug further into the application to and see exactly at what point the issue is reproduced.  Like, if you retrieve the value _immediately_ after setting it (and do any necessary casting for the type) then does the issue still happen?

Comment: Hey @David, after you comment I decided to go through the whole app and rewrite a few clunky bits. Seems to have solved the problem :) Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Keep per-user data somewhere either in `Session` or in `Cookie`.